# Find a chain of subsets of $\mathbb N$ with certain propreties in the $\subset^*$ relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having a really bad time working in this problem, and it turned out that I'm really stuck. It is from a first course in Set Theory.

We are using that  "$A\subset^* B$" if the set of the elements of $A$ that do not belong to $B$ is finite.

Show that there is a family $T \subset \mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ of infinite sets with the following properties:
- If $A,B \in T$, then $A \subset^* B$ or $B\subset^*A $
-There is no infinite $C \in\mathcal P(\mathbb N)\setminus T$ such that $C \subset^*A$ for all $A \in T$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Use Zorn's lemma to produce a maximal $T$ with the first property, and show that maximality implies the second property.

Comment: How do I get to the maximal T with Zorn's lemma?
I've tried building T as the maximal element (provided by Zorn's lemma) to the set of all chains of infinite sets of P(N), but for now this sounds weird.

Comment: How do you get a maximal linearly independent set of vectors in a vector space using Zorn's lemma? How do you obtain a maximal ideal using Zorn's lemma? These uses are not different. Define a partial order whose elements are the relevant families of sets, order it by inclusion, and show it satisfies the conditions of Zorn's lemma.

Comment: I wonder how the instructor would respond to an appeal directly to the Hausdorff maximality principle!

Comment: @Brian: By pointing out that the maximality principle is stated for partial orders, and this is not a partial order. :-)

Comment: But $[\omega]^\omega/\text{Fin}$ is. Actually, that’s probably enough extra work to satisfy a reasonable instructor even if the HMP hasn’t been covered.

Comment: @Brian: Yes, I agree. But then you have to make the way "back" from that partial order. What would be interesting is how would an instructor respond to an appeal to cardinal invariants "Since $\mathfrak t>0$, it is necessary that such family exists in the first place." :-)

Comment: How about: ‘What the devil are you doing in a first course in set theory?!’

Comment: @Brian: *Bzzz* Wrong answer, thanks for playing! The correct answer would be "The definition of $\frak t$ is the least cardinality of a family with these properties; in order to prove that $\mathfrak t>0$ you need to first prove that such family exists in the first place. Therefore the suggested argument is circular." :-)

Comment: Not circular, for precisely the reason that you give: if you’ve shown that $\mathfrak{t}>0$, then you’ve shown that such families exist. (In other words, I interpreted the suggested argument differently from the way you intended it. I didn’t realize that you intended the most superficial interpretation.)

Comment: @Brian: Oh, yeah, you gave me much more credit than deserved. :-P